# Multiple categories for a single post

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help with something, I've got three tables

```
1. filmi | film_nr...
2. kategorite | kat_nr, emri_kat
3. film_kat | film_nr, kat_nr....
```

EX:

```
filmi 1
kategorite 3
           4
film_kat 1 3
         1 4

SELECT *, fk.kat_nr, f.film_nr AS fnr
FROM filmi f   
  INNER JOIN film_kat fk ON f.film_nr = fk.film_nr   
  INNER JOIN kategorite k ON fk.kat_nr = k.kat_nr   
ORDER by f.film_nr desc
```

I use this to fetch rows:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultati)) {
```

and when I fetch the result from kat_nr to get the name of categories, for every query I get a new div, and when I use GROUP By only one category name appears, I want to show categories with commas.

```
<?php 
    $sql = "
    SELECT *,fk.kat_nr,f.film_nr AS fnr FROM filmi f
    INNER JOIN film_kat fk ON f.film_nr = fk.film_nr
    INNER JOIN kategorite k ON fk.kat_nr = k.kat_nr
    ORDER by f.film_nr desc
    ";
    $rezultati = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($rezultati) > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultati)) {
   echo '<div class="filmi">';
    echo '<a href="film.php?nr='. $row["fnr"] .'" title="'. $row["emri_kat"] .'">'. $row["emri_film"] .'</a>';
    echo '<div class="fotografija">';
     echo '<img src="'. $row["imazhi_url"] .'" alt="">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="pershkrimi">';
     echo '<p>Vlersimi: <strong>'. $row["imdb"] .'</strong>/10</p>';
    echo '</div>';
   echo '</div>';
    }
    }
   ?>
```

The categories are displayed in link title

Comment: Can u please paste ur output here.

Comment: Where does the div come in?

Comment: GROUP BY, with GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: I want to thank you a lot jarlh !

Comment: You're finished already? Great! If you add your solution, others can read and learn from it!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of jarlh, I did it!
The only thing you need is group concat

```
SELECT *,fk.kat_nr,f.film_nr AS fnr,group_concat(`emri_kat` separator ',') as `katname` FROM filmi f
INNER JOIN film_kat fk ON f.film_nr = fk.film_nr
INNER JOIN kategorite k ON fk.kat_nr = k.kat_nr
GROUP by f.film_nr
```